# C# - How to make my assembly strongly named?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to create unit tests for some of my private methods and I read that you can access them from your unit tests via `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DLLName")]`.

However, mine's not working and another solution was to add the Public Key. I tried to get the Public Key of my unit test project via `sn -Tp DLLName` but it is complaining that it isn't strongly named.

How can I make it so that it is strongly named? Am I using the `InternalsVisibleTo` the wrong way?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247123(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if you go to the properties of your project, on the side bar there should be a navigation link called "Signing". There should be an option to sign the assembly. If that is not there, then I don't think you can give it a strong name?

Answer (score 3):

Chances are your unit test assembly *isn't* strongly named at the moment - after all, it's a relatively unusual requirement, as the reasons for strong naming don't often apply to test assemblies.

However, the use of `InternalsVisibleTo` *does* necessitate this - because it's a bit like you're adding a reference from the strongly-named production assembly to the test assembly, and you can't refer to a non-strongly-named assembly from a strongly-named one.

So just make the test assembly strongly named in the same way as you have for the production assembly (Project Properties, Signing), give it a key (e.g. the same one as your production assembly) and *then* use `sn -Tp` to get the public key.

All this is assuming that the reason your original `InternalsVisibleTo` attempt didn't work *because* the production assembly is strongly-named. If it isn't, then signing the test assembly won't help at all, and you need to give us more information about the problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

**To create and sign an assembly with a strong name using the Assembly Linker**

At the command prompt, type the following command:

```
al /out:<assembly name> <module name> /keyfile:<file name>
```

In this command, assembly name is the name of the assembly to sign with a strong name, module name is the name of the code module used to create the assembly, and file name is the name of the container or file that contains the key pair.
The following example signs the assembly MyAssembly.dll with a strong name using the key file sgKey.snk.

```
al /out:MyAssembly.dll MyModule.netmodule /keyfile:sgKey.snk
```